# How to fix pixel homing into origin?

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to make a pixel rotate around a graph in C++ and it keeps slowly going towards the middle of the graph and I don't know why or how to fix it.

I've tried doing this in desmos and it worked fine.

I think it's caused by rounding errors but I don't know.

The way I'm transforming the graph is `x2 = x1 * cos(theta) - y1 * sin(theta)` and `y2 = x1 * sin(theta) + y1 * cos(theta)`

The framework I'm using is Chili Framework 2016.

Here is the code:

```cpp
/****************************************************************************************** 
 *  Chili DirectX Framework Version 16.07.20                                              * 
 *  Game.cpp                                                                              *
 *  Copyright 2016 PlanetChili.net <http://www.planetchili.net>                           *
 *                                                                                        *
 *  This file is part of The Chili DirectX Framework.                                     *
 *                                                                                        *
 *  The Chili DirectX Framework is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify   *
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by                  *
 *  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or                     *
 *  (at your option) any later version.                                                   *
 *                                                                                        *
 *  The Chili DirectX Framework is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,        *
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of                        *
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the                         *
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.                                          *
 *                                                                                        *
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License                     *
 *  along with The Chili DirectX Framework.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  *
 ******************************************************************************************/
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#define kb wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed

Game::Game( MainWindow& wnd )
    :
    wnd( wnd ),
    gfx( wnd )
{
}

void Game::Go()
{
    gfx.BeginFrame();   
    UpdateModel();
    ComposeFrame();
    gfx.EndFrame();
}

// width: 1200
// height: 1000

const int width = 1200;
const int height = 1000;

// dom = [0, 1199]
// range = [0, 999]

// pixel1 coords
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

int pixelX = 0;
int pixelY = -400;


int xTransform(int x1, int y1, double angle) {
    return (x1 * cos(angle)) - (y1 * sin(angle));
}

int yTransform(int x1, int y1, double angle) {
    return (x1 * sin(angle)) + (y1 * cos(angle));
}

int graphParseX(int x1) {
    return x1 + 600;
}

int graphParseY(int y1) {
    int temp = y1 * -1;
    return temp + 500;
}

void Game::UpdateModel()
{
    // draw graph
    for (x = 0; x < width-1; x++) {
        gfx.PutPixel(x, height / 2, 255, 255, 255);
    }
    for (y = 0; y < height-1; y++) {
        gfx.PutPixel(width / 2, y, 255, 255, 255);
    }

    // draw rotating pixel1
    gfx.PutPixel(graphParseX(pixelX), graphParseY(pixelY), 255, 255, 255);
    gfx.PutPixel(graphParseX(pixelX)-1, graphParseY(pixelY), 255, 255, 255);
    gfx.PutPixel(graphParseX(pixelX)+1, graphParseY(pixelY), 255, 255, 255);
    gfx.PutPixel(graphParseX(pixelX), graphParseY(pixelY)-1, 255, 255, 255);
    gfx.PutPixel(graphParseX(pixelX), graphParseY(pixelY)+1, 255, 255, 255);
    gfx.PutPixel(graphParseX(pixelX) - 2, graphParseY(pixelY), 255, 255, 255);
    gfx.PutPixel(graphParseX(pixelX) + 2, graphParseY(pixelY), 255, 255, 255);
    gfx.PutPixel(graphParseX(pixelX), graphParseY(pixelY) - 2, 255, 255, 255);
    gfx.PutPixel(graphParseX(pixelX), graphParseY(pixelY) + 2, 255, 255, 255);


    if (kb(0x45)) { // rotate right

        // debug
        gfx.PutPixel(801, 800, 255, 255, 255);
        gfx.PutPixel(802, 800, 255, 255, 255);
        gfx.PutPixel(803, 800, 255, 255, 255);
        gfx.PutPixel(800, 800, 255, 255, 255);
        // debug

        pixelX = xTransform(pixelX, pixelY, -1 * M_PI/24);
        pixelY = yTransform(pixelX, pixelY, -1 * M_PI/24);
    }
    if (kb(0x51)) {

        // debug
        gfx.PutPixel(401, 800, 255, 255, 255);
        gfx.PutPixel(402, 800, 255, 255, 255);
        gfx.PutPixel(403, 800, 255, 255, 255);
        gfx.PutPixel(400, 800, 255, 255, 255);
        // debug

        pixelX = xTransform(pixelX, pixelY, M_PI / 24);
        pixelY = yTransform(pixelX, pixelY, M_PI / 24);
    }

}
void Game::ComposeFrame()
{
}
```

Here is a recording of what happens: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GkEolvN0Ws5Q_Inb7rLAThglHWJ9LPEM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you try asking Chili directly? He's pretty active on YouTube, Discord, and Twitter. https://planetchili.net/

Comment: @Casey thanks for responding, I figured it out already. if anybody is wondering in the future, I have separate variables for x and y before and after rotation. i use x and y to calculate the position after the rotation but don't set it to that, as that caused it to round down.

Comment: Post your fix as an answer and then set it as accepted. It makes the Community bot user and algorithm happy. :)

Answer (score 1):

if anybody is wondering in the future, I have separate variables for x and y before and after rotation. i use x and y to calculate the position after the rotation but don't set it to that, as that caused it to round down.